# Flutter camera - Same code behaves very different on two apps

Tags: flutter

I am developing a camera feature for my app. I started with a separate project that only contains code for camera. I have gotten that to work as I want. So I thought I could just use the exact same code to record videos and show them afterwards on my other app by just using the same code.

That did not work as intended.

[image: Screenshot from my test project]
[image: Screenshot from the app I want to add my camera feature]

The reason is that there are two back cameras on my phone. But how can I use the one with a wide angle? I am currently selecting camera like this:

```
try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print("Could not find cameras: $e");
  }

for (var description in cameras) {
      if (description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back) {
        onNewCameraSelected(description);
      }
    }
```

This should choose the first back-facing camera. But apparently that is not deterministic. In one case I get a narrow angle and in the other a wide angle.

I have temporarily solved this by adding a button so the user can switch camera. Seems to be some info missing in the description?

Comment: Code always chooses the first one in the list: cameras[0].

Comment: Sorry, tested if it was indeed the different back facing cameras manually. Updated now.